# Need to center responsive gallery content

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, centering, jquery-isotope

Here is the website I'm working on:
https://frankli-n.github.io/portfolio/memsmosaics/filter/filterable-gallery/dist/m_index.html#gallery

If you scroll down to the images/gallery section, and narrow the window, or view on mobile, you will see that the as the width decreases, the number of columns of images decreases in a responsive manner. This is good, but I want the columns to be centred, not aligned to the left. I don't know how to achieve this.

Note that there is also an option to click the blue square which toggles the image view setting from responsive-aligned-left mode, to 3-column-centered mode. I quite like this toggle feature, I just wish the responsive-aligned-left would still be centered. This would make the 1 column mobile view look a lot better.

[image: images not centered]

Thank you for any help

EDIT: It looks like I need to do something which will change the javascript that positions the img tags with

```
style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
```

Comment: You could use `flex` display and then align it to center its simple CSS.

Comment: I have centered an element before with CSS. I'm finding this more difficult because I'm tangled up in Javascript code that I don't understand properly.